# How we can run function only once inside scroll() in jquery

Tags: jquery, foreach, scroll

I have a code inside a scroll function, want to run it only once.How can I achieve it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  ('.bar').each(function(){
   //some code
  });
 });
});
```

here each function is running again and again as I scroll. What change should I do to run it only once.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: When the code you wanted to execute has finished you could unbind the scroll event ```$(window).unbind('scroll');```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I want to create code, where when the element come inside the viewport,only than code for animating that element should work and that only once after that I don't want to run that again and again.